# Nginx - How to full url redirect with pattern from old domain

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I have a website that I've changed it zone last two days, there are some shared posts in all over the social networks, i want to redirect any user from the old domain to the new one, the problem is i get a full 301 Permanent Redirect to the main page not to that specific URL.

The redirect is handled by CloudFlare, in the roles page, I've created two forward roles as following:

https://myold.com/posts/* > https://mynew.org/posts/* < **302 Temporary Redirect**

https://myold.com/* > https://mynew.org/* < **301 Permanent Redirect**

Whats wrong here? do i have to use a different pattern? or i must do the redirect from **Nginx** server?

Comment: Hi there. Are you able to use a CNAME in your DNS ? Looks like a bettter approch for you.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas, Hi, do i need to use cname to to a full redirect? would it be better to use a forward redirect?

Comment: If you use a CNAME the redirect will be performed at DNS level so your customers will not even reach your backend. But, I do see that you will need a CNAME for the root, and that is not possible. Now, what error do you get on the redirect? What do you see in the browser?

Comment: I see nothing! no errors! i get a redirect to the main page not to that specific post!

Comment: CNAME redirect its all about a host and a value which is the website url! i want to redirect the user to a post he would like to read from **www.myold.com/post/123** to **www.mynew.org/post/123**

Answer (score 1):

Hooray!! I got it to work, I just needed to match the pattern with the URL.

The main URL should look like this: ***myold.com/***
The new URL address must have a parameter to match what goes after *, so it should lool like this: **https://mynew.org/$2**

Now I get a full redirect to the same URL.